# Can i get blob pdf content from encoded url in php

Tags: php, file, pdf, filereader

I have a BLOB URL that has the pdf file with the content:

```
blob:http://localhost/468479b7-7db1-4e35-ab35-acf9ff0739f8
```

Using the filereader i convert it to base64:

```
var myReader = new FileReader();
var blob = new Blob([v.src], {type: "application/pdf"});
myReader.readAsDataURL(blob);

   myReader.onload = function(event) {
        result = event.target.result;
        console.log(result);
        console.log(v.src);
   };
```

The result is:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,YmxvYjpodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0LzQ2ODQ3OWI3LTdkYjEtNGUzNS1hYjM1LWFjZjlmZjA3MzlmOA==
```

Now can i get the pdf content from the encoded url?

If not, what are my options?

Comment: Well that is something base64 but that is not a PDF as it does not start with the correct bytes

Answer (score 2):

Extract the content part. Decode and save into a file.

```
    $data = explode(';',"data:application/pdf;base64,YmxvYjpodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0LzQ2ODQ3OWI3LTdkYjEtNGUzNS1hYjM1LWFjZjlmZjA3MzlmOA"); 
    $encoded = explode(',',$data[1]);
    file_put_contents("test.pdf",base64_decode($encoded[1]));
```